# Regression/classification, how to accommodate the missing columns of data?

Tags: regression, classification, data-mining, prediction, weka

I would like to apply any regression methods, such as the ones available using WEKA libraries (for example, SVMs, NNs, Random Trees,...) . However, I am getting very low results since I am missing the relevant columns of data.

I am posting this question since doing the internet search gives the results regarding the situations when there are missing data-points and not the whole data-sets.

What would be the best way, if any, to accommodate the missing columns and get better regression results ? What I need is something that would mock the missing data in such a way, that would yield the better statistical results regarding the prediction results.

I have tried clustering, and than doing the regression per cluster. That does improve the results, but the improvement is not a significant one.

Furthermore, I have tried applying the regression methods multiple number of times, but that does not do anything at all for a data-set I have.

Mocking the data by adding a random data column improves the training (sometimes), but not the actual prediction.

Any help or a hint would be more than appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't cross-post. Choose the most appropriate site for your question & post it only once. This Q is probably better suited here, so you may want to delete [the copy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26077214/1217536) on SO.

Comment: Deleted, with an enthusiasm.

Comment: What do you mean by 'missing the relevant columns of data'? What do you use as inputs and labels/outputs?

Comment: It is all numeric. By missing columns of data I mean the columns that are essential to calculating a result but are not present in a data sample. For example (bluntly speaking!), if you want to predict how many days someone is old, and all you have is the day and hour of birth, but do not know the year of birth, the missing column would be "Year of Birth". What I need is a method that would mock the year of birth to enable me to get better regression results.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could come up with is to generate the columns of some numeric patterns, and to use the symbolic regression with the programs such as Eureqa, to train to R and R^2 up to 0.95, and then to use those patterns and (sequence of Eureqa) formulas with another data-set to do another training/predicting.

If you do not use any functions such as smart-moving averages, instead of generating the patterns, simply enable the option to use integers and consants with Eureqa and have your original data as input columns.

The problem is, symbolic regression takes a lot of time to complete, and the end-result might give solutions that take a lot of time to compute.

As a side-note, taking the neural-net approach and overtraining the sample-data did nothing!

I am not sure if I am explaining this well, so if you want more details, just contact me any-time!

PS I am still waiting for someone else's solution for this post.